# theano gives "...Waiting for existing lock by unknown process..."

Tags: python, gpgpu, theano

My code was working fine. However, now I am getting an error that says:

```
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GT 750M
WARNING (theano.gof.cmodule): ModuleCache.refresh() Found key without dll in cache, deleting it. /Users/mas/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-14.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.10-64/tmpcm9_P6/key.pkl
INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): Waiting for existing lock by unknown process (I am process '2799')
INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): To manually release the lock, delete /Users/mas/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-14.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.10-64/lock_dir
```

I delete the folder lock_dir, but I still get the same message.

Comment: Are you using multiprocessing?

Comment: yes I am using multiprocessing.

Comment: If you wait, does it continue eventually? It might take many minutes for a function to compile and only one function can be compiled at any one time.

Comment: I thought so as well and waited but no response. @danielrenshaw

Comment: The first warning looks suspicious. Maybe try deleting the entire `.theano` directory?

Comment: Thank you @DanielRenshaw . deleting .theano solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by adding the following code to my  ~/.theanorc :

[global]
 base_compiledir=/tmp/%(user)s/theano.NOBACKUP

Comment: Hi there, how can you do this directly from my python code?