# How to get rid of theano.gof.compilelock?

Tags: python, keras, locking, theano

I am using the joblib library to run multiple NN on my multiple CPU at once. the idea is that I want to make a final prediction as the average of all the different NN predictions. I use keras and theano on the backend.

My code works if I set n_job=1 but fails for anything >1.

Here is the error message:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 3 concurrent workers.
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Overriding existing lock by dead process '6088' (I am process '6032')
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Overriding existing lock by dead process '6088' (I am process '6032')
```

The code I use is rather simple (it works for n_job=1)

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
result = Parallel(n_jobs=1,verbose=1, backend="threading")(delayed(myNNfunction)(arguments,i,X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test) for i in range(network))
```

For information (I don't know if this is relevant), this is my parameters for keras:

```
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
os.environ["MKL_THREADING_LAYER"] = "GNU"
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '3'
os.environ['GOTO_NUM_THREADS'] = '3'
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '3'
```

I have tried to use the technique proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035632/theano-gives-waiting-for-existing-lock-by-unknown-process) but it didn't change a thing. To be precise I have created a file in C:\Users\myname.theanorc with this in it:

```
[global]
base_compiledir=/tmp/%(user)s/theano.NOBACKUP
```

I've read somewhere (I can't find the link sorry) that on windows machines I shouldn't call the file .theanorc.txt but only .theanorc ; in any case it doesn't work.

Would you know what I am missing?